# Java springdoc-openapi show LocalDateTime field with additional date/time fields in Swagger UI Example Value

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, springdoc, localdatetime

spring-boot 2.6.2
springdoc-openapi 1.6.2

**Single** field `LocalDateTime dateTime` in body represent in Swagger UI Example Value as

```
{
  "dateTime": "2022-01-21T10:02:46.481Z",
  "time": {
    "hour": 0,
    "minute": 0,
    "second": 0,
    "nano": 0
  },
  "date": "2022-01-21"
}
```

Date format can be fixed (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1276885/209226) by

```
    static {
        var schema = new Schema<LocalTime>();
        schema.example(LocalTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME));
        SpringDocUtils.getConfig().replaceWithSchema(LocalTime.class, schema);
    }
```

But it is still remained 3 fields iso one `dateTime`:

```
{
  "dateTime": "2022-01-21T10:05:52.945Z",
  "time": "13:05:14.746",
  "date": "2022-01-21"
}
```

UPDATE:

In object for `LocalDateTime dateTime` field I've aux methods `getDate/getTime`.

```
public LocalDate getDate() {
    return dateTime.toLocalDate();
}

public LocalTime getTime() {
    return dateTime.toLocalTime();
}
```

They are ignored in json, as of fields based jackson configuration, but NOT ignoring in springdoc.
Fixed with `@Schema(hidden = true)`

Answer (score 4):

if you want a better representation you need to add a type, in my case string.
See Docs (https://swagger.io/specification/)

```
static {
            var schema = new Schema<LocalTime>();
            schema.example(LocalTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"))).type("string");
            SpringDocUtils.getConfig().replaceWithSchema(LocalTime.class, schema);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't help. But I've found reason, wrote UPDATE.

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin Developer:

```kotlin
@Configuration
open class SwaggerConfig{
    init {
        val schema: Schema<LocalDateTime> = Schema<LocalDateTime>()
        schema.example(LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")))
        SpringDocUtils.getConfig().replaceWithSchema(LocalDateTime::class.java, schema)
    }
}
```